# How can I retrieve data from array

Tags: php, arrays

Am a beginner in yii2. In my program there is an array named `Place`. It contains the values like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aluva
            [1] => Paravoor
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ernakulam
            [1] => Paravoor
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aluva
            [1] => Ernakulam
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kottuvally
            [1] => Paravoor
        )

)
```

How can I retrieve each element from this array?

Comment: Assuming that the array lies inside variable called `$Place` (e.g. you were able to print it with `print_r($Place)`), you should be able to access individual elements like this: `$Place[1][0]` will yield `Ernakulam`

Comment: Got it.Thank you @yeputons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array_walk function

```
$total = [];
array_walk($sales, function($value) use(&$total) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $arr) {
        echo $arr. "<br>";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using foreach ?

```
foreach($array as $row){
    foreach($row as $key => $val){
         echo $val.'<br>';    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code -

```
<?php
$data = array(
        0 => array(0=>'Aluva', 1=>'Paravoor'),
        1 => array(0=>'Ernakulam', 1=>'Paravoor'),
        2 => array(0=>'Aluva', 1=>'Ernakulam'),
        3 => array(0=>'Kottuvally', 1=>'Paravoor')
    );


foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo '<br>'.$value1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = $Place[0][1];
```

Where is `$var` is now "Paravoor"